# Is the ASUS Radeon R9 390 STRIX 8Gb a product that would be advisable to buy?

Tags: graphics-cards

**I currently have a MSI R9 380 GAMING 4Gb card**, and was wondering how it would compare to my current card?
(**E.G. performance to dollar wise**)

And if not **what would be a viable alternative** for around 300 dollars?

Current PC:
- GIGABYTE LGA 1150 INTEL B85 SATA3 MATX MOBO
- Intel i7-4770k
- 32 gb DDR3 ram
- Msi R9 380 4gb
- 750w corsair CX750
- Intel 750 series 480 gb ssd
- Fractal Design Define R4 case

**EDIT:** I'm asking for hardware recommendations; I've now edited this and included bolded important sections.

Comment: What are you going to do with your GPU that requires all this power?

Comment: I'm planning on triple 1440p monitor setup using display port, as well as using it for folding at home and other shared computing projects.

Comment: What exactly will you do on this triple monitor setup? Gaming? Viewport? The more specific your requirements are, the better we can help.

Comment: Gaming, sorry I should have been more specific.